# Resetting Wi-Fi connection on Windows without rebooting

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, reset

I have connected to my school Wi-Fi, with password authentication; once I logged off or close my laptop, and log back in, despite me typing the correct password, I cannot recover the network connection, it says authenticating...

The problem can be resolved by restarting Windows, but I found it very annoying to reboot and recently my hard disk is known to die at any time due to liquid damage, so I try to reboot as seldom as possible.

Is there any way I can reset the Wi-Fi without rebooting? I tried using the troubleshoot problems option in windows, it's not helpful at all

Comment: A few quick suggestions: **`1.`** From an elevated command prompt run `net stop "WlanSvc" /Y` and wait for it to stop. Then from that same command prompt run `WlanSvcnet stop "WlanSvc"`. **`2.`** From network settings or network and sharing center in the Control Panel, go to Change adapter settings, find the WLAN adapter, right click disable, and then right click enable. **`3.`** Go to Device Manager, find the WLAN device, right click disable, and then right click enable to re-enable it. Let me know if you find any of this helpful or worthy of an answer to your question and I'll do so.

Comment: You should be able to complete either ONE of those and test after each toggle one-by-one to see which works best and is easiest for you to complete. You do NOT need to do all three, so any one of these solutions should do the trick to disable and then re-enable the WLAN adapter.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the network adapters on your device, use these steps:

1. Open *Settings*.
2. Click *Network & Internet*.
3. Click *Status*.
4. Under the *Change your network settings* section, click the *Network reset* option.

   [image]
   <sup>Source: Windows Central</sup>
5. Click the *Reset now* button.

   [image]
6. Click the *Yes* button.

And you have successfully rest the Wi-Fi connection on Windows without rebooting. In case if the problem still exists please refer Read this post: [Troubleshoot laptop Wi-Fi connection](https://www.0gadget.com/how-to-troubleshoot-laptop-wi-fi-connection/), but you will need to restart with the PC/Laptop.